# Failed to load ApplicationContext when using @Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, caching, javabeans, ehcache

I'm integrating Caching into my web application but for some reason Application Context failed to load when adding the @Cacheable annotation.

I have been trying to solve the issue for two days now, your help is really appreciated!

app.context.xml

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="EhCacheManagerBean" key-generator="customKeyGenerator" />

<bean id="EhCacheManagerBean" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcacheBean" />

<bean id="ehcacheBean" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:EhCache.xml" p:shared="true" />

<bean id ="customKeyGenerator" class="com.app.site.v2.cache.customKeyGenerator"/>

<bean id="siteService" class="com.app.site.v2.SiteService" primary="true"/>
```

EhCache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true"
     monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<cache name="cacheSite"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

Method that is being cached

```
public class SiteService implements ISiteService {

    @Cacheable("cacheSite")
        public JsonObject getSiteJson(String siteId, boolean istTranslated) { ... }

}
```

Exception that is being thrown

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'siteService' is expected to be of type 'com.app.site.v2.SiteService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57'
```

Comment: Does it work without the annotation? Where does runtimeService bean come from?

Comment: @CrazySabbath yes if I remove the annotation it works!, I updated the post!

Comment: You have both concrete class and interface with the same name `SiteService` - which one is `com.app.site.v2.SiteService`?

Comment: @yegodm I updated the post, sorry for the misleading!

Comment: That means somewhere you have a dependency to concrete class `com.app.site.v2.SiteService` instead of interface `ISiteService`. Since caching likely uses proxying, the dependency fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of @yegdom is actually the right answer. When adding the `Cacheable` annotation, Spring generates a proxy which implements `ISiteService`. And somewhere in your code, you have a bean requiring `SiteService`, the implementation.

There are three solutions (in preference order):

- Remove the useless interface... A single implementation is just adding complexity for no direct benefit. Removing it will force Spring to use a class proxy
- Fix your dependency to use `ISiteService`
- Add `proxy-target-class="true"` to `cache:annotation-driven` to tell Spring to create a class proxy

I really do not recommend the last one since you should always depend on the interface or always depend on the class (and delete the interface). Not both at the same time.